# Expressing subtext of story characters

Tags: word-choice, nuances, dialogue

Context:

A gets B to go to eat at a restaurant for the couples-only item in the restaurant, stating that A themselves don't know anyone else that can pretend to be a couple with them. However, B points out that A's sister could be a possible and viable choice, and A doesn't deny that.

(I believe that the subtext here is that A was actually asking B out for a date.)

Less important is that A has been lying to B for a bit before, and this is the first time B called A's bluff.

---

> A: まいったなぁ　バレちゃったか
>
> [...]
>
> B: Aは相変わらず不思議で何を考えてるのかよくわからないけれど　**ひとつ、ウソを見破る事ができたみたいです**

1. Am I right to assume that B was only happy for picking up the lie, but is still unaware of the ulterior motive of A, without the context that B is emotionally inexperienced?
2. If so, how could the sentence be changed to show that B knows of both the lie and that A was treating it like a date?

I've thought of a few alternatives to the bolded sentence that attempt to show that B also knows the ulterior motive:

> "I'm finally starting to understand A, bit by bit."
>
> だんだんAの事が分かるみたいです
>
> "I can fully understand what he's thinking, at least for this situation."
>
> 今日だけ、考えてるのは何か分かるみたいです
>
> "At least now I know that he was treating it as a date."
>
> せめて今、デートと思ってた事を知っています

(sorry for the rough Japanese TL)

---

More preceding context as requested by comments:

> A: B その後さ、ちょっと宿りたいとこがあるんだ　付き合って貰ってもいい？
>
> [...]
>
> A: ありがとうB　カップルのふりしてくれて　Bが甘いもの好きで良かったよ　*他に頼めるな子もいないし本当に助かった*
>
> B: 気にしないで下さい　ボクもお腹すいてたから
>
> B: (あ、美味しい…　これくらいの甘さならCも平気かも…　Cにも教えてあげたら喜ぶかな…)
>
> A: 今、Cの事考えてたでしょ？
>
> B: えっ⁉なんで分かったんですか？
>
> A: エスパーダからだよ
>
> B: す、凄い…！
>
> A: ウソだよね
>
> (B reacts to it like being betrayed)
>
> [they talk a bit about C]
>
> B: そういえば…　D甘いものが苦手なんですか？ (D is A's sister)
>
> A: え？そんなことないよ？俺より甘党だけど　どうして？
>
> B: あ、いや…ちょっと気になっただけで…　パンケーキ、Dの事は誘うなかったのかなって　*ほかに頼める人もいないって言ってたから*…
>
> A:　あー　なるほどね…
>
> A: まいったなぁ　バレちゃったか
>
> [...]
>
> A: パンケーキ食べたことは、２人だけの秘密だよ　CとDには内緒　ね？
>
> B:　…はい！
>
> B: (Aは相変わらず不思議で何を考えてるのかよくわからないけれど　**ひとつ、ウソを見破る事ができたみたいです**)

Comment: Could you provide the part of the dialogue that precedes the part you quoted, where A tries to trick B into going to the restaurant with them and then gets caught in "the lie"? Right now I'm not sure if the lie B speaks of is really A claiming that they don't know anybody suitable for the pretend couple thing or disguising their motive for going to the restaurant with B.

Comment: Without further contexts, the lie B found out looks like that A's motif was having a date with B. You need to clarifying a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 1, I think you are correct. The lie referred to in the last phrase seems to be that A asked D for going to the restaurant.

Regarding the second question, it depends on the character which of the sentences are most probable, so I simply give more natural translations:

- だんだんAのこと(**が**)わかって**きた**みたいです
- 今日だけ**は**, **Aの**考えてる**ことが**(or Aの考えが)分かるみたいです。
- **少なくとも**今**は(もう)**デート**だ**と思ってたことを知ってます(or 思ってたことはお見通しです may be better).

Grammatically what you should check may be contrastive は which was missing in the 2nd and 3rd sentence.